# Terraform failing to set some attributes for GCP Compute Engine during deploying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I am using `terraform` to import the state of existing `GCP Compute Engine Resource` so that the resource can be later managed with `terraform`

I imported using below command

```
  terraform import google_compute_instance.default <project-d>/us-east1-b/server-001
```

After that I executed `terraform show` to identify the state of existing resources and copy pasted the output of it to `main.tf` file .

Now when I do `terraform plan` it shows below errors

```
   Error: "label_fingerprint": this field cannot be set
   # google_compute_instance.default:
   on main.tf line 2, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
   2: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {

   Error: "current_status": this field cannot be set
   on main.tf line 2, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
   2: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {

   Error: "network_interface.0.name": this field cannot be set
   on main.tf line 2, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
   2: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {

  Error: "instance_id": this field cannot be set
  on main.tf line 2, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
  2: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {

  Error: : invalid or unknown key: id
  on main.tf line 2, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
  2: resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
```

Following are the lines of code

```
project              = "<Project-ID>"
current_status       = "TERMINATED"
name                 = "server-001"
hostname             = "server-001.example.com"
id                   = "projects/<project-id>/zones/us-east1-b/instances/server-001"
instance_id          = "7335818403011119952"
labels               = {
    "env"    = "dev"
    "server" = "app"
}
machine_type         = "f1-micro"
zone                 = "us-east1-b"
boot_disk {
    auto_delete = true
    device_name = "server-001"
    mode        = "READ_WRITE"
    source      = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projec-id>/zones/us-east1-b/disks/server-001"
    initialize_params {
        image  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-7-v20200309"
        labels = {}
        size   = 10
        type   = "pd-standard"
    }
}
 network_interface {
    name               = "nic0"
    network            = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projec-id>/global/networks/adminproject-vpc"
    network_ip         = "10.3.0.2"
    subnetwork         = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projec-id>/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/app-subnet"
    subnetwork_project = "<project-id>"
}
```

`Terraform` version is as follows

```
   $ terraform version
     Terraform v0.12.24
    + provider.google v3.29.0
```

Removing these attributes fixes the issue but can't we set these attributes while creating the manifests file for terraform ? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fields cannot be managed by Terraform. They may be used in the configuration of other resources but cannot be modified on the `google_compute_instance` resource itself, as they are delegated by GCP. You can look at the supported arguments for the `google_compute_instance` resource [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/compute_instance.html).